# How to get a page to react to information provided on the homepage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

My homepage consists of a form with drop-down options, specifically city names (i.e., New York, LA, Miami, etc...) When a user picks a city, he/she is redirected to another page, which is supposed to display deal results (call this the deal page).

Basically, I am wondering how to get the deal page to display information based on the city picked on the homepage? I am using queries to retrieve results, but I want the queries to change based on the city picked so that the information of the deal page is relevant.

If the answer is too detailed, can someone point me to the specific topic that this relates to and maybe a website that provides answers?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like this would just be a simple HTTP GET.. is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I am using google app engine with Jinja2. Should I be using Django?

Comment: I am creating a deal aggregator as a side project. I am having difficulties trying to figure out how to have the deal page react based on the city chosen.

Answer (score 0):

For the dropdown, add an on Change listener that redirects to a different url. The url could be something like process.php?city=Maine

To add an onchange listener

```
document.getElementById('citydropdown').addEventListener('change', myFunc, false);
```

To redirect in javascript:

```
window.location = newUrl;
```

Comment: @Brett: Then the URL will be "something like process.py?city=Maine" instead. If you can't even know that much, you probably need to read a basic tutorial or take a class before trying this project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an onchange event in the select. Here is an example: http://lab.artlung.com/dropdown/
By the way: using onchange="window.open(url, '_self');" is like a redirect to an url.
To get the value from the user selected option use: onchange="window.open(this.value, '_self');"